# Multivariate constraint optimization in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, pyomo

I have exact hessian and jacobian for a nonlinear constraint optimization problem. It has multiple variables like x,y each with different dimension and bounds. Is it possible to encode it in scipy easily? If yes, how. If not, what is the best way?

```
min f(x,y)
s.t. g(x,y) >=0
     h(x,y) = 0
```

Comment: The [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function accepts both the Jacobian and Hessian callables as arguments. The bounds on your Jacobian and Hessian are harder to incorporate, since no solver uses both the Hessian and constraints or bounds.

Comment: The problem is about multiple variables. size of x = [2,3,4], size of y = [4,5]

Comment: What is the difference between `x` and `y`? Can't you just combine it into one vector?

Comment: I ended up doing that. It was easier to write it like in gams or ampl.